# How do you paste an image into an edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to copy an image from the browser or your phone and be able to paste it into an edit text.

When I try to paste an image into an edit text it says "[App name] does not support image pasting here."

I also want it so you can get the data of everything in the edit text so I can upload it to a database and get it from the database into a text view.

Is it possible? If not is there something that supports image paste and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a recycler view that can insert images from phone, write text, edit text, delete text and delete images.